# WordPress Site URL auto change

Tags: wordpress

I have migrated a WP site from Siteground to another Siteground temporary domain using Siteground migrator. After I migrate that new site auto-redirect back to the old site.

I have updated SITE_URL and HOME from PHPmyAdmin. But after I refresh the new site those records are automatically changing back. Any method to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these.

- Define the SITE_URL and HOME constants in the wp-config.php file. [Changing Site URL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)
- Rename the plugin directory so the plugins are all disabled. Might be something in one of the plugins that are changing the values.

Answer (score 0):

I find SiteGround's KB quite helpful here:

https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_configure_wordpress_to_work_with_a_new_domain/

Also, they have a built-in URL search & replace tool in Site Tools WordPress section, which is what you will need most.